# Does it make sense to alter this DB Schema with indexed columns for binary filtering to increase query performance?

Tags: mysql, database-schema, database-performance

Writing some queries on a DB with 12+ million rows on a laptop running Windows7-Home with 4GB of memory (college professor with no research budget).  I am considering adding the following columns to the schema as utf8_bin and placing indexes on them.  Will this give me better query performance? A simple query like the following take 100+ seconds:

```
SELECT 'Aug' as Month, 
        SUM(volume) AS Volume 
FROM    moving_avgs
WHERE   data_date between 20120801 
        AND 20120831;
```

- The columns I would add and index:

  - Year
  - Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri
  - Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr ... Dec
  - OpExp

My current table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `moving_avgs` (
  `symbol` varchar(8) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `data_date` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `openprice` double(13,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `highprice` double(13,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lowprice` double(13,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `closeprice` double(13,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `prior_close` double(13,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pror_e` double(8,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pror_l` double(8,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `volume` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `exchange` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `ma5_open` double(13,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ma10_open` double(13,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ma20_open` double(13,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ma30_open` double(13,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ma50_open` double(13,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ma90_open` double(13,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ma200_open` double(13,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ma5_high` double(13,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ma10_high` double(13,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ma20_high` double(13,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ma30_high` double(13,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ma50_high` double(13,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ma90_high` double(13,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ma200_high` double(13,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ma5_low` double(13,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ma10_low` double(13,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ma20_low` double(13,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ma30_low` double(13,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ma50_low` double(13,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ma90_low` double(13,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ma200_low` double(13,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ma5_close` double(13,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ma10_close` double(13,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ma20_close` double(13,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ma30_close` double(13,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ma50_close` double(13,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ma90_close` double(13,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ma200_close` double(13,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ma5_volume` int(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ma10_volume` int(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ma20_volume` int(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ma30_volume` int(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ma50_volume` int(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ma90_volume` int(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ma200_volume` int(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `volt5_l` double(8,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `volt10_l` double(8,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `volt20_l` double(8,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `volt30_l` double(8,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `volt50_l` double(8,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `volt90_l` double(8,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `volt200_l` double(8,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `volt5_e` double(8,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `volt10_e` double(8,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `volt20_e` double(8,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `volt30_e` double(8,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `volt50_e` double(8,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `volt90_e` double(8,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `volt200_e` double(8,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`data_date`,`symbol`,`exchange`),
  KEY `symbol` (`symbol`),
  KEY `data_date` (`data_date`),
  KEY `exchange` (`exchange`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Is there anything I could do with my.ini?

```
[mysqld]
port        = 3306
socket      = /tmp/mysql.sock
skip-external-locking
key_buffer_size = 128M
max_allowed_packet = 20M
table_open_cache = 256
max_heap_table_size = 128M
tmp_table_size = 512M
sort_buffer_size = 512M
read_buffer_size = 32M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 16M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 128M
thread_cache_size = 8
query_cache_size= 64M
basedir=c:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.5.24
log-error=c:/wamp/logs/mysql.log
datadir=c:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.5.24/data
# Try number of CPU's*2 for thread_concurrency
thread_concurrency = 8
```

Below is the result from the EXPLAIN for:

```
explain select 'Aug' as Month, sum(volume) as Volume from moving_avgs
where data_date between '2012-08-01' and '2012-08-31';

id select_type table       type  possible_keys     key     key_len ref  rows   extra
-- ----------- ----------- ----- ----------------- ------- ------- ---- ------ -----------
1  SIMPLE      moving_avgs range PRIMARY,data_date PRIMARY 3       NULL 110906 Using where
```

Thanks much!

Comment: Can you post the explain-plan output for the query? That will tell you if the index is being used.

Comment: The EXPLAIN has been added to the question.

Comment: I would try adding an [index hint](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/index-hints.html) to make it use the `data_date` index instead of the composite primary key.

Comment: Thanks Jim @JimGarrison. I learned something new. I was not aware of `index hints`.  I will try them. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your table definition you dont have any secondary indexes on the table. Since your query is using a date range to determine which records to return and there is no index on it the query will perform a table scan.

Adding the other indexes and columns will probably slow things down during inserts and updates so DONT add them yet.

Just add a index on the data_date column so that the query can use this index to speed up the read. I would suggest if you could to post the result of the following statement in your question:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT 'Aug' as Month, 
        SUM(volume) AS Volume 
FROM    moving_avgs
WHERE   data_date between 20120801 
    AND 20120831;
```

This will show me the query plan and I would be able to confirm that it is a table scan and not  using a index. Being able to read the output of the explain statement is a very important part of query optimization.

Comment: There are 4 keys on the table already. Scroll down on the table definition section and you will see them.

Comment: @Dr.EMG thanks for pointing that out. I missed that somehow. Could you still post the output of the explain statement though?

Comment: I have updated my question to show the EXPLAIN for sum() query.